# Как применить интерфейс к переменной В Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, typescript

У меня есть интерфейс
`export interface TaskInterface{ name: string description1: string time: string }`

```
import { TaskInterface } from '@/types/task.interface'
```

и переменная `

```
data () {
    return {
      tasks: [{
        name: 'Create app',
        description1: 'Use smth ',
        time: '02.12.2021'
      },
      {
        name: 'Fix bugs',
        description1: 'Fix all bugs',
        time: '02.12.2021'
      }] as TaskInterface[]
```

но мне не выдает ошибку если я сделаю `name : 123,

Как применить интерфейс к переменной Vue.js?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка возникает потому что вы указали тип переменной `name` в `string` и получаете ошибку, пытаясь присвоить тип `number`. Исходя из этого если вы получаете ошибку, связанную с интерфейсом - значит этот код работает и интерфейс присвоен объекту. Если переменная `name` может содержать несколько типов данных, то они должны быть описаны в интерфейсе, например так:

```
export interface TaskInterface {
    name: string | number
}
```